# How to make tag attribute ID in HTML unique not to override it on your Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a unique ID on my HTML and i am referencing more than once to my J query document. Each time when i try to access that element ID it override to other ID and causing data not to orchestrate it well. Meaning it then becomes not parallel to what i am expecting it to output data as CSV. Please this logic for me clarity.

```
<!---Downloading File using 
Jquery with Buttons---->
  <div class="form-group"><br>
  <div class="col-md-1.9 text-center">
   <button id="download" name="download" 
    id = "nav-ask"class="btn btn-warning" >Download</button><br>
    </div> 
  </div>

// checking for one field entry to read.
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#nav-ask').click(function() {
            var xcount = 0;
            if($('#temperature').prop('checked')) xcount--;
            if(xcount < 1) {
            window.location.href ='https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/899906/fields/1.csv';
            }
          });
  });

  // checking for two field entry to read.
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#download').click(function() {
      var ncount = 0;
      if($('#illuminance').prop('checked')) ncount--;
      if(ncount < 1) {
        window.location.href = 'https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/899906/fields/2.csv';
      }
    });

  });

  // checking for third entry to read.
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#download').click(function() {
    var qcount = 0;
    if($('#button-state').prop('checked')) qcount--;
      if(qcount < 1) {
       window.location.href = 'https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/899906/fields/8.csv';
      }
    });

  });
```

Problem here is data duplication, how do i make it to be unique for my first field? Meaning to my checkbox so it wont be exposed to other element ID. second ID and third ID for the fields works well, the issue on the first on, it jumps to reference others field8 each time when its invoked in the browser.

Comment: You appear to have 2 `id` on your button, you can only have 1 `id="nav-ask"` and `id="download"`

Comment: @Carsten Lovbo Andersen, i was testing that second ID to see if it can works. I first used download on the first field(checkbox), while others you saw are used. So the issue ID(download) if i used it throughout, it will ignore the other field and reference the last field(button-state) and output those results on REST API. I dont want that at this stage, it will confuse the user when reading the data. I want it to be unique throughout to all my checkbox, so that Jquery will load document successfully.